# Records with combination of associated record

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have a model `Product` with many `property_products` associated and I want to fetch all products with combination of two or more property_products.

I tried:

```
Product.joins(:property_products)
  .where("(property_products.property_id = '2' AND property_products.value= '195')
      AND (property_products.property_id = '3' AND property_products.value = '65')"
  )
```

but it doesn't return any records.

```
Product Load (1.5ms)  SELECT "products".* FROM "products" INNER JOIN "property_products" ON "property_products"."product_id" = "products"."id" WHERE ((property_products.property_id = '2' AND property_products.value= '195') AND (property_products.property_id = '3' AND property_products.value = '65'))
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>
```

I also also tried:

```
Product.joins(:property_products)
  .where("property_products.property_id = '2' AND property_products.value = '195'")
  .where("property_products.property_id = '3' AND property_products.value = '65'")
```

but the result was the same.

Comment: adding the generated SQL would be helpful

Comment: it may be a valid results, are you sure that it should return records? :

Comment: Your query will never match any records. You are trying to get products whose *each* property_product has the `property_id = 2 and value = 195` AND `property_id = 3 and value = 65`, which will never be the case. One property_product can only have one property_id and value.

Comment: @TamerShlash Could you help me getting products with one property_product with `property_id = 2 and value = 195` and the other one with `property_id = 3 and value = 65`?

Comment: @szpon sure, but I have one more question: can a product have 2 property_products with the same property_id and value? e.g can there be 2 property_products whose property_id = 3 and value = 65?

Comment: @TamerShlash no, product can't have multiple property_products with one `property_id`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Altough Tamer Slash's solutions works, I found more elegant one:

```
Product.joins('join property_products as p1 on products.id=p1.product_id')
.joins('join property_products as p2 on products.id=p2.product_id')
.where('p1.value = 195 AND p1.property_id = 2')
.where('p2.value = 65 AND p2.property_id = 3')
```

Answer (score 1):

Your query will never match any records. You `where` clauses mean the following:

> The following 4 conditions must be fulfilled for *every single* `property_product`:
>
> - have property_id = 2 AND property_id = 3 (which will never happen on a single record)
> - have value = 195 AND value = 65 (which, also, will never happen on a single record)

Instead, you want your query conditions to be something like:

> The following conditions must be fullfilled for every single *product*:
>
> - It must have an associated `property_product` whose product_id = 2 AND value = 195
> - and it must have *another* associated `property_product` whose product_id = 3 AND value = 65

Given the fact you provided in the comments...

> that "product can't have multiple property_products with one `property_id`

...this is one way to do it using plain SQL:

```
product_ids = ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute('
                select product_id, count(product_id)
                from property_products
                where (property_id = 2 AND value = 195)
                OR (property_id = 3 AND value = 65)
                GROUP BY product_id
                HAVING count(product_id) = 2')
              .map { |i| i['product_id'] }

products = Product.where(id: product_ids)
```

Notice that `HAVING count(product_id) = 2` is purely because you are matching with 2 `property_products`. Update the number as you change the conditions.

Ofcourse, that's not the most elegant solution in Rails, there might be better ones. But this is just a quick & dirty solution.

Answer (score 0):

Your query

```
Product.joins(:property_products).where("
  (property_products.property_id = '2' AND property_products.value= '195')
  AND
  (property_products.property_id = '3' AND property_products.value = '65')
")
```

will never match any record. Perhaps, you misspell `OR` to `AND` ?

```
Product.joins(:property_products).where("
  (property_products.property_id = '2' AND property_products.value= '195')
  OR
  (property_products.property_id = '3' AND property_products.value = '65')
")
```

Comment: I want to get products having two `property_products`. Using `OR` will also give me products having only one of them.